# Current time and date in C++20 days

Tags: c++, c++20

I fast read the C++ reference about new chrono classes but I found them a little bit complicated.

So, the question is, how to re-write this code in C++20, to get year, month, day, hour, minute, second?

Are there any changes? I ask because of this minor problem with `std::localtime`: It is thread-unsafe. `tm` will be destroyed after next call to `std::localtime`.

```
std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
std::tm *tm = std::localtime(&t);
int year = tm->tm_year + 1900;
int month = tm->tm_mon + 1;
int day = tm->tm_mday;
int hour = tm->tm_hour;
int minute = tm->tm_min;
int second = tm->tm_sec;
```

Comment: HowardHinnant/date is the incubator project that led to the calendar facilities in C++20. Check out the "Examples and Recipes" wiki page here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#components_to_time_point

Comment: In particular: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#components_to_time_point, but it needs to be adapted for local time.

Comment: Basically, you *shouldn't* try to rewrite that code in `chrono`. The whole idea of chrono is that you keep things like dates and times in its format for as long as possible, so that type information and the like can be kept around. That is, you only turn them into `int` or whatever when you need to communicate with something that *cannot* access chrono's data structures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <chrono>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    // Get a local time_point with system_clock::duration precision
    auto now = zoned_time{current_zone(), system_clock::now()}.get_local_time();

    // Get a local time_point with days precision
    auto ld = floor<days>(now);

    // Convert local days-precision time_point to a local {y, m, d} calendar
    year_month_day ymd{ld};

    // Split time since local midnight into {h, m, s, subseconds}
    hh_mm_ss hms{now - ld};

    // This part not recommended.  Stay within the chrono type system.
    int year{ymd.year()};
    int month = unsigned{ymd.month()};
    int day = unsigned{ymd.day()};
    int hour = hms.hours().count();
    int minute = hms.minutes().count();
    int second = hms.seconds().count();
}
```

I've tried to explain what each line of code does with a comment.  I'm happy to elaborate further if anything is not clear.

This is all threadsafe.

**More information:**

Another and perhaps even more concise way to compute `now` is:

```
auto now = current_zone()->to_local(system_clock::now());
```

This results in the exact same type and value for `now`.

I used `zoned_time` above because it is (in general) a higher-level abstraction than calling member functions of a `time_zone` directly.  In both examples the type of `now` is a simple `std::chrono::time_point` that is offset from `system_clock::time_point` by the UTC offset associated with the `time_zone` at this point in time.

In contrast `zoned_time` carries much more information.  For example it knows about:

- The name of the `time_zone`.
- The abbreviation for the `time_zone` at this point in time.
- The UTC offset of the `time_zone` at this point in time, and subsequently can produce both the local time and the UTC equivalent time.
- The valid range of the offset/abbreviation pair.

Therefore a `zoned_time` is much more flexible for jobs like formatting as it can display the abbreviation and/or the UTC offset.  And a `zoned_time` can also be more easily used to find out the equivalent time in other time zones.

Nevertheless, all of that extra information isn't actually used in this simple example, and is thus why I'm exposing the alternative of calling the `to_local()` member function of `time_zone` directly.

For the simple case of finding the local time, both techniques have identical behavior and performance, so it comes down to a matter of readability for choosing the preferred approach.